# Azure Devops - how to delete an old running job in an agent pool where the release is expired and no longer retained

Tags: azure-devops

I have this stuck job running in a devops agent pool (for 586 days now!) and I cannot find a way to delete it. The release which it comes from is no longer retained (30 day retention), so therefore when I click on the job I cannot cancel it. Devops website returns

"VS402939: Release with ID ##### does not exist. Specify a valid ID and try again."

Tried deleting the agent which is running the job using the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) but this returns a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.TaskAgentJobStillRunningException.

Any help would be appreciated. T